# How to get date from OnDateSetListener into a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

How can I get date which is selected from the `DatePickerFragment`?

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    int Year,Month,Day;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
}
```

My `Fragment` in which I want to get date and set it to a text field:

```
public class CalculatorHomeFragment extends Fragment

LinearLayout lyDate;
TextView lblDate;
int Year,Month,Day;

private static CalculatorHomeFragment instance = null;

public CalculatorHomeFragment() {

}

public static CalculatorHomeFragment getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new CalculatorHomeFragment();

    return instance;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator_home, container, false);
    lyDate = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lyDate);
    lblDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblDate);
    lyDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I am getting date in the DatePickerFragment's onDateSet method but i want it in the main fragment which is CalculatorHomeFragment.

Comment: You need to add communication between activity and the fragment to update values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the first class to get DataPicker, just change your onClickListener like this:

```
lyDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dateDialog= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), datePickerListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dateDialog.show();

    }
});
```

And add an OnDateSetListener in your class like this:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String dateYouChoosed = dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;
        lblDate.setText(dateYouChoosed );
    }
};
```

Comment: How can i use the `lblDate.getText().toString(); ` to get the date set in `lblDate.setText(dateYouChoosed );` ?